# Google map not filling modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a modal popup when users click the map [on this page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/nightlife/pubs/horse-and-groom-593.html#myModal), which brings up a larger map with directions.

The map isn't filling the entire space however and I can't figure out why. When I right click on it to check in an the chrome inspector, it makes the map fill the modal.

Excuse all the code, but I thought it best to include it all:

```
       <div class="map clearfix">
            <div class="bg left-contact">
            <% if len(""&rsAdvert("ContactPostcode"))>0 then %>
                      <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
<div class="small-map" style="width:100%;height:130px;background:url(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<%=server.URLEncode(""&rsAdvert("ContactPostcode"))%>&zoom=14&size=250x250&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|<%=server.URLEncode(""&rsAdvert("ContactPostcode"))%>&sensor=false) center no-repeat;"></div></a>
                      <div class="expand"></div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><div id='map-canvas'></div></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
               <% end if %> 
            </div>
        </div>

     <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?q=London&key=AIzaSyBaPEDyFbbnWjtvT8W3UBOM34Y7g6vK69A&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var geolocate = function(address, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
                        data: {
                            "sensor": true,
                            "address": address
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(d) {
                            if (d.status == "ZERO_RESULTS") callback(false);
                            if (d.results && d.results[0] && d.results[0].geometry) {
                                callback({
                                    "ne": d.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast,
                                    "sw": d.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest,
                                    "center": d.results[0].geometry.location
                                });
                            }
                            else callback(false);
                        }
                    });
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
          geolocate("<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>", function(c) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(c.center.lat, c.center.lng));
         });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger a `resize` event on the map, after the modal is launched, which will cause it to resize to fit the dimensions of the containing `div`. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size

```
// Add this at the bottom of the script which defines your map
// It will trigger the resize event on the map after the modal has launched
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
})
```

I think when you launch dev tools the `window.onResize` event is causing the `resize` event to be triggered on the map. You can prove this by detaching dev tools from the browser window before clicking your modal.

Comment: Thank you, do I put that in a separate <script> tag? Not sure how to incorporate it as I'm just learning javascript..

Comment: It shouldn't matter where in the page you put it, as long as the `map` variable is defined.

Comment: You'll have to do it after you've launched the modal.

Comment: You can play around with the code above in the console in dev tools (just paste it in and hit return). I just pasted it in after your page had initialised and then launched the modal. The map hadn't resized. When I ran the code again with the modal visible, the map resized. I think you probably need to figure out how to set a callback or catch an event for the launching of a Bootstrap modal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I really wouldn't know how to do that. Seems odd it won't fit it.

Comment: As far as I can make out from the docs, that's the method you're supposed to use. See my updated answer which shows how you can trigger the event after the modal is shown. Remember that the documentation is your friend (the Google maps documentation especially is outstanding) - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Also, what specifically would you not know how to do?

Answer (score 4):

For completeness: if you're using [Bootstrap modal window](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you need to use `shown.bs.modal` event in place of `shown` event.

Here the code:

```
  $("#modalWindowId").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(markerLatLng); // Set here center map coordinates
  });
```

Take a look here for learn more:
http://coderpills.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/showing-google-map-inside-a-bootstrap-modal-window/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

padding: 0;

Css:

```
.modal-body {
max-height: 400px;
overflow-y: auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how the padding effects it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. Just to help anyone else that may have this problem, in addition to having to resize due to having the map in a modal, I also had to reset the center.

The below code needed to be added within the `initialize` function.

```
    $('#show_map').on('shown', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Map_Modal_ID').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    initialize();
});
```